# Where is Ranmir. I am trying to complete Drowned Sorrows mini-quest

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

Where is [Ranmir](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Ranmir)?

I am trying to complete the [Drowned Sorrows Quest](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Drowned_Sorrows)

This is a mini-quest from what i can gather of forums and does not list as a quest in my log.

I have managed to complete most of the quest and all that is remaining is to give the letter to Ranmir. However, I cannot find him.

I have gone in and out of the Frozen Hearth tarvern at different times. I have even left the whole place and done other quests, including loading and saving and waiting. I have tried his sisters shop and even sneaked in at night to check beds.

I do not believe he is dead and have not fought a dragon in Winterhold since meeting him. He must be alive, just can't find him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sorry to tell you that but it is possible that Ranmir is dead. Have you finished the questline of *College of Winterhold* yet? There is a huge battle during that questline where he might got killed.

This is an extract from a [Wiki-Site](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Ranmir):

> Haran might give the quest even if Ranmir is dead.
>
> It is possible for him to be killed during the College of Winterhold
>   questline. Upon returning to Winterhold to fight Ancano and destroy
>   the Eye of Magnus, that the Magical Anomalies attacking the town can
>   kill Ranmir, or he will be reanimated by Arniel Gane during the fight
>   with the anomalies, after which—assuming he isn't re-killed—he will
>   proceed to go into his house, and turn into an ash pile at the door.

When I did this quest there were some citizens killed so it is possible that Ranmir got killed, too.

**Edit:**

As we know, Haran can also give you the quest when Ranmir is dead. We should check if Ranmir is dead. You can use the following console command to teleport to the location of Ranmir:

```
player.moveto 0001C18B
```

0001C18B is the *Ref ID* of Ranmir. This should teleport you to his location. I can't test it right now, so I don't know what happens when you try to teleport to a dead NPC.

I would consider this cheating, but since you really have looked everywhere for him, it might be the only way.

Comment: I had finished the College quests and had the huge battle. Sometime after that I got the quest from Ranmir. I had spoken to Haran, but she referred me to Ranmir. I immediately completed the quest but now cannot find Ranmir.

Comment: I updated my answer with another solution.

Comment: Can this be done with an Xbox360? I had tagged the question as that but some bright chap removed the tag.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I don't think that's possible... *The console is a powerful in-game tool only available to PC players.* from a Wiki-Site. I tried it on my PC and Ranmir was still in the Tavern of Winterhold. Looks like you have to keep looking for him throughout Skyrim. I'd propose after 5 days of searching you can pronounce him dead. :) Sorry, I don't have better news for you.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that Ranmir is dead. If you have done the college of winterhold you should know that threre is a battle and Ranmir could have got killed in it because when I did the quest a NPC got killed although you don't need to know that. Or there is a possibility that he gliched out of the game and disserpered. But if you've looked everywhere ,not done the college of winterhold and no enymis have killed him then I don't know what you can do.

Comment: I too think that is what happened to him.

Comment: This happened to my on PS3. I've read somewhere else online that it is a scripted event. It's a shame because I really wanted to finish the side quest with Ranmir alive